# What could cause discord.VoiceChannel.edit() to have major performance issues?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a Discord bot using the [discord.py library](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#), and I want to add a feature where it updates a voice channel's name every time someone joins; for example, it starts as "zero noobs" with no one connected and changes to "one noob", "two noobs", etc. as people connect or disconnect.

I tried implementing this with `Bot.on_voice_state_update()`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before: discord.VoiceState, after: discord.VoiceState):
    # Change name of noobs channel upon change in number of connected members
    try:
        if (before.channel.id == CHANNEL_ID or after.channel.id == CHANNEL_ID)\
        and before.channel != after.channel:
            await _edit_noobs()
    # Either before.channel or after.channel is None (user connected/disconnected)
    except AttributeError:
        await _edit_noobs()
```

where `_edit_noobs()` is a helper function:

```
async def _edit_noobs():

    myserver = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == GUILD_ID, bot.guilds)
    channel = discord.utils.find(lambda c: c.id == CHANNEL_ID, myserver.voice_channels)

    nums_strs = ("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
    num_connected = len(channel.members)

    try:
        num_str = nums_strs[num_connected]
    # More than ten members connected (just in case)
    except IndexError:
        num_str = "a lot of"

    # Handle singular form
    if num_connected == 1:
        noobs = "noob"
    else:
        noobs = "noobs"
    
    await channel.edit(name=f"{num_str} {noobs}")
```

I've tested this code with `print()` statements numerous times, and there doesn't seem to be a problem in the logic (the functions run when they should, and the variables assume the values they should). The problem is the `await channel.edit()` line takes a very long time to execute. When I was testing the bot, it could successfully change the channel name 2-3 times in quick succession, but after that it lags - changing the name minutes after an event. I don't see any notes on potential performance issues in the documentation, nor have I seen questions regarding this. I'm not too familiar with how coroutines work in Python and discord.py, so is there something that could be causing my `await` statements to lag so much?

Also: `discord.utils.find()` and all other lines execute almost instantly (tested with `print()` statements); the only lines that didn't were the `await` statements.

Comment: The ratelimit for editing channels is 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel, you’re simply hitting them. And no, there’s no way to bypass them.

Comment: I didn't know that. That's unfortunate. Thanks for the reply!